# Rails query has_many association with Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using the Geocoder gem to get geocode `Locations`, of which belongs_to an `Event`.  An  `Event` has_many `Locations`.

I'm needing to return a query of all Events that are `.near` (Geocoder method) a `params[:zipcode]`.

The first line below returns the correct collection of @locations, but I don't know how to include `Event`s that have those `Locations` since they are an array of Locations.

```
@locations = Location.near("#{params[:zipcode]}", params[:within])
@events = Events.joins(:locations).where(location: {any of the @locations})
```

I feel like this is pretty simple...but I'm running a blank!

Is it possible to make this one line?  Something like:

```
@events = Events.joins(:locations).where(location: address.near("#{params...})
```

The `Location` table has `:address :latitude :longitude` in the db (geocoded by :address).

Location model:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode
end
```

Event model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :locations, dependent: :delete_all
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

Comment: Can you please add code of location model and event model ?

Comment: Please check my answer let me know if its not working

Answer (score 1):

please write below code in Event model

```
reverse_geocoded_by 'locations.latitude', 'locations.longitude'
```

or

```
geocoded_by       'locations.address'
```

After writing this code you can directly hit near query for Event model like

```
Event.near("#{params[:zipcode]}", params[:within])
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method locations.address for #<Event:0x00007f989c9d4158>`

Comment: @Alex add `geocoded_by       'locations.address'` after `has_many :locations`  or you can also try reverse_geocoded_by but you must write after association of locations

Comment: It was after.  There are multiple locations for an Event.  Can you have multiple geocoded_by records for an event if their are multiple associated records that are geocoded?

Comment: @Alex i done it in my application and it is working fine.

Comment: @Alex did you tried `reverse_geocoded_by 'locations.latitude', 'locations.longitude' ?
`